# Docker volumes are partitions or subdirectories?

Tags: docker, filesystems

I declare a new volume in runtime with `-v` flag in `docker run` command. What is the created volume? Partition or only a subdirectory? Could be it maybe formatted to another filesystem(If `Docker` supports other fs, than `AUFS`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using "-v" is created a link between the host folder to container. The files created in container linked folder, that documents will be stored in folder of host.

About other FS. Docker supports AUFS, btrfs, vfs, and DeviceMapper:

https://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/

Comment: Than only one another question: How can I create a fully separated volume inside a container?

Comment: Please! Create another question here. Avoid more questions in comments :)